# LibGDX: Skin and scaling problems

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to use Skins with TextButtons. However I'm having an issue where the TextureRegions of the Skin are NOT being scaled down to the tablesize.

This is leading to an issue like in this image:

[image]

As you can see that is the e from the word Hello. I managed to scale that down to a more reasonable size (still wrong). However the Button textures are still way too large.

[image]

Any ideas? Because I am pulling my hair out. I am using a custom viewport with a custom screenspace width and height. Here is the create method for the menu.

```
    public void create(){
    menuStage = new Stage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewPort = new StretchViewport(SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, SCREEN_SPACE_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewPort.setWorldSize(SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, SCREEN_SPACE_HEIGHT);
    menuStage.setViewport(viewPort);

    devTexture = new Sprite (new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/16by9.png"), true));


    Image newActor = new Image(devTexture.getTexture());
    newActor.setSize(
            viewPort.getWorldWidth(),
            viewPort.getWorldHeight()
    );

    menuStage.addActor(newActor);
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

    menuTable = new Table();

    skin.getFont("default-font").setScale(0.08f);

    menuTable.debugAll();

    menuTable.setFillParent(true);
    TextButton a,b,c;

    a = new TextButton("hello", skin);
    b = new TextButton("hello", skin);
    c = new TextButton("hello", skin);

    a.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    b.getStyle().up.setMinHeight(2.0f);
    b.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    c.getStyle().up.setMinHeight(2.0f);
    c.getStyle().up.setMinWidth(2.0f);

    menuTable.row();
    menuTable.add(a).size(2.0f, 1.0f);
    menuTable.add(b).size(2.0f, 1.0f);
    menuTable.add(c).size(2.0f, 1.0f);

    menuStage.addActor(menuTable);

    camera.translate(
            newActor.getWidth() / 2,
            newActor.getHeight() / 2
    );
}
```

Comment: Scaling anything leads to degradation. This is even true in 3D graphics.

Comment: I understand that. However that is not the issue. The skinned buttons were rendering correctly before, until I switched to a custom coordinate system. The TextureAtlas and font belonging to the skin is however using (I assume) a different coordinate system. How do I get them to use the same?

Comment: I have had scaling problems where my image size exceeds the size it needs to be in game using a custom coordinate system. If this is the case try scaling up your coordinate system. You can still use your virtual width and height, just scale those numbers by a fixed number whenever you use or need them.